# Is there a way to cover a campfire and keeping bees calm when harvesting?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

According to [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Beehive#Harvesting):

> Placing a carpet above the campfire leaves room for the bees to hover beneath the nest and still avoid taking fire damage. In Java Edition, the smoke coming through the carpet also calms the bees. In Bedrock Edition, **a carpet is treated as an obstruction that removes the calming effect of the campfire's smoke**.

I tried and this works the same with trapdoors (as confirmed on [Mojang bug tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-60937)).

So, is there a workaround?
I'd like to harvest my beehives without taking fire damage AND without making bees angry against me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The campfire page of the wiki says much the same thing, that there must be nothing between the campfire and the nest, and that carpets are a Java version exception. Otherwise I would have suggested other non-full blocks like glass panes or chains.

I typically put the bee nest at ground level and put the campfire one block underneath it. That way the fire is not accessible and cannot damage me or the bees, but still allowing me and the bees to access the nest.

Comment: Well, maybe not what I asked, but it's definitely a very good solution.

Comment: @pinckerman Yeah, seems Bedrock is too restrictive so I tried to offer an alternative. Do *open* trapdoors block smoke? You might be able to arrange a trapdoor to face towards you while open, blocking you from touching the fire, while possibly still letting the fire through.

Comment: Already tried, open trapdoors are considered as an interruption. Hiding the campfire below ground level is by far the best solution.